# App Store submission - only developer signatures accepted

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I faced a very strange behaviour recently. Seems I cannot submit apps signed with my Distribution certificate. When I try to validate my app Xcode complains that "Unable to process application info.plist validation at this time due to a general error". If I try to submit I receive the error that I am using an invalid signature.

That made me thinking. I revoked all my certificate. I deleted all my provisioning profiles and had recreated them. Same error occurred.

Some recommended to wait a few hours as it is an apple server problem. Waiting a whole night did not resolve my problem.

And then I tried to use for code signing my iPhone Developer certificate and the related Provisioning Profile.Rebuilt and you know what? Boom, it went through. I checked zillions of times. I am unable to submit an app by signing with Distribution Identity and Distribution Profile. I can use my Developer Identity and Profile for that.

What do I miss here? I submitted my app at least 50 times to the store so it is not the first time I try to do so. I am sure it is my mistake somewhere but still I cannot find it.

I checked with `codesign  --display --verbose=4` and got this result:

> Identifier=com.XXX
>
> Format=bundle with Mach-O thin (armv7)
>
> CodeDirectory v=20100 size=2555 flags=0x0(none) hashes=119+5
>   location=embedded
>
> Hash type=sha1 size=20
>
> CDHash=76e31baa45948f8e2eb6283ab754da934df04ab6
>
> Signature size=4328
>
> Authority=iPhone Developer: MY NAME (AAAAAAA)
>
> Authority=Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
>
> Authority=Apple Root CA
>
> Signed Time=28 Jan 2014 06:40:56
>
> Info.plist entries=32
>
> Sealed Resources version=2 rules=5 files=120
>
> Internal requirements count=1 size=188

Yes the above was accepted by ITMS and my app is waiting for review.

I would really appreciate your explanation.

Regards,

Teddy

Comment: It could very well be a bug on Apple's end. Go to bugreport.apple.com and file it. I think this should be closed as it's not really a question, is it?

Comment: That is what I thought. But this "bug" exists for two weeks now. Apple approved my Apps twice since that and I am sure that others were facing similat problem. I just want to understand if it is the normal way to submit or I miss something somewhere.

Comment: It may be that the bug requires something exceptionally unique about your signature and app for it to manifest itself. Send the bug report as best you can to Apple and they'll probably reply within a month or so asking for additional details. You might also give calling or emailing the Apple ID or ADC or iTC staff a try - I had some funky issues with my Apple ID preventing me from logging on to ADC several months ago… something about my account being so old that it was missing a flag entirely that all new accounts have that let them access ADC, or something like that.